# unable to open url after lock screen

Tags: android

My code to open url in browser is

```
private void openBrowserUrl(String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    System.out.println("============Url==================" + url);

    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
    unlock(UNLOCK_TO_HOME);
}
```

Above is working fine when there is no pattern lock.

But When I tried to open browser after pattern lock, url value remain blank.

I have custom lock screen in my application.. When phone is locked, after that, I tried to unlock the phone at that time custom lock screen is opened by my application. and in that I have written this code. I got url value and it successfully passes to browser.

But, I tried with above process with patter lock(default lock system of android)

then the flow is

custom lock screen-->open url code(got the url value)-->default pattern lock-->browser without url value.

In above flow, when pattern lock is there, browser unable to get url which I have passed.

Comment: from where you are invoking the method openBrowserUrl(String url), please investigate the life cycle as well

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs on api > 21. There been some changes in the KEYGUARD, and after you unlock the screen there is some kind of a delay or something that makes the intent not to react,buy using the flags it should delay the intent and make it work
the code here should solve the problem.

```
       getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("your url"));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getActivity().startActivity(i);
```